# expanding multidimensional arrays with a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to get the multidimensional array values from an array using a foreach loop. But it just says undefined index name

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
    $main[]['id'] = $row['categories_id'];
    $main[]['name'] = $row['categories_name'];
}
foreach($main as $m) {
    $main_filters .= '<li>'.$m['name'].'</li>';
}
```

so sure what I am doing wrong here, any ideas, i.e. how do I get the multidimensional values of all the elements in the array array $main, id and name?

Comment: as answered below but also you dont need 2 loops, do it all in one

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Comment: Yes, this is far more simple with one loop.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$main[]['id'] = $row['categories_id'];
$main[]['name'] = $row['categories_name'];
```

with

```
$main[] = [
    'id' => $row['categories_id'],
    'name' => $row['categories_name']
];
```

otherwise you create two new element in each iteration, and you don't want that.